# Windows 7 dual monitors 1 - DVI 2 - HDMI For HDMI to see a picture pressing Auto button is required

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I used to have dual monitors both connected via DVI. After Windows login wallpaper( picture ) was immediately avaialable on a second one. The problem started for my newly assembled computer where a graphics card has a single DVI +  HDMI + mini DisplayPort.  Now after login I have to press "Auto" button on the bottom of HDMI monitor. If HDMI monitor was made main in "Screen resolution" I have to press "Auto" to see Windows login screen. The same monitor button key pressing is required each time  after exiting  from "Sleep" mode

Comment: It sounds like your HDMI monitor is "listening" for input signal from another source. Check if it has multiple inputs? And if so, try and change the priority in the monitor's own settings, not Windows.

Comment: You are quite right . On the monitor's Menu > Extra > Input Select must be set to HDMI in my case ( was Auto ) . Probably because when Auto is pressed the menu 
D-Sub
DVI
HDMI
is shown where DVI before HDMI 
Though HDMI is highlighted it doesn't seem to be sufficient to turn monitor on immediately.